# Which datatype is used to store video files

Tags: oracle, oracle-10g, datatypes

I am working on a web application using JSP.

I want to ask which datatype(with syntax) is used to store video files in Oracle database.

Comment: What database engine are you using?

Comment: I I am using ORACLE 10g

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You probably shouldn't be storing the video in the database at all.  Just store the metadata about it in the database and put the video itself on a filesystem, which is much more appropriate for storing such stuff.

More details in the two good answers at [Images, PDF, audio and video files in MySQL](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/36564/images-pdf-audio-and-video-files-in-mysql) - of which this question is arguably a duplicate.

Comment: interMedia is largely used to do what I'm suggesting: put the video in the filesystem (using Oracle's BFILE type) and store the metadata about it in the database; it just allows one to do it in one of Oracle's several-somewhat-standard ways.  The pros and cons of storing the data as a BLOB within the database given at the question I referred to are quite apropos; that it's about MySQL is irrelevant.

Comment: It's fabulous suggestions I got it  thanks to all IT  genius

Answer (score 2):

> Oracle Multimedia (formerly known as Oracle interMedia) lets you write applications to manage images, audio,video, and other heterogeneous media data in Oracle databases.

I have referenced **interMedia** as you are using Oracle 10g.

[interMedia User's Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/appdev.102/b14302/ch_intr.htm)

Here is a nice answer given by [Justin Cave](https://stackoverflow.com/users/10397/justin-cave), which explains why would a person store a video file in a BLOB in a database and what are the advantages and disadvantages compared to storing pointers to the location of the video file.

[BLOB's in SQL that stores a Video file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7623306/blobs-in-sql-that-stores-a-video-file)

Comment: Doing it this way would lock you into using Oracle; it would become hard to switch to another DBMS?

Comment: @MatthewElvey do folks just switch databases every day? if you're going to use a platform, use it to the best of its ability, not to the lowest common denominator..and yes, i'm biased